# Does this constitute a valid proof that $\frac{x^2}{1+x^4} \leq \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification

> Prove that $$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4} \leq \frac{1}{2}.$$

First off, we observe that the expression on the LHS is positive for all $x \in \Bbb R,$ and equality is achieved iff $x \in \{-1, 1 \}$. That being said, we start by manipulating the expression as below;

\begin{align}
\frac{x^2}{1+x^4} - \frac{1}{2} &\leq 0\\\\
\impliedby\frac{2x^2 - (1+x^4)}{2(1+x^4)} &\leq 0\\\\
\impliedby -\frac{(x^4 - 2x^2 + 1)}{2(1+x^4)}&\leq 0\\\\
\impliedby \frac{x^4 - 2x^2 + 1}{2(1+x^4)} &\geq 0\\\\
\end{align}

We then make the observation that $x^4 - 2x^2 + 1 = (x^2 - 1)^2 \geq 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ and that $1 + x^4 \geq 1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$, and so the final inequality holds for all $x \in \Bbb R. \\\hspace{92pt}\square$

Is it okay to prove it in this way? I have no solutions so it would be nice if I could have some validation!

Comment: Your arrows point in the wrong direction.  The expression $A\Rightarrow B$ means "If $A$ then $B$".  And $A\Leftarrow B$ means "If $B$ then $A$". You have them pointing to the right where you need them pointing to the left. $\qquad$

Comment: Better? Thanks.

Comment: Your first step should be to WLOG and convert it to $\frac {x}{1 + x^2} \le \frac 12$ in the positive domain.

Comment: I would find this clearer if it were written in the opposite direction. Start with what is known and end with what you want to prove, instead of the other way around.

Comment: @Ed_4434 Concerning 'arrows' all the lines are in fact *equivalent*.

Comment: @OlivierOloa : Yes, the arrows could go both ways: $A \Longleftrightarrow B$.  The ones going to the left are the ones that matter.  But now that we have dealt with the crucial point of logic, I'd say I'd use such arrows far more sparingly than that. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy Thanks for your feedback. Anyway I wouldn't have given a downvote for the observed typo.

Comment: @OlivierOloa : Neither would I.  I up-voted the question when it had received only one up-vote so far. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's Ok, you could also just multiply both sides by $2(1+x^4)$ having to prove that
$$
2x^2\le x^4+1
$$ that is
$$
0\le(x^2-1)^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I have an unbridled fear of clearing denominators in case I drop solutions by doing so!

Comment: @Ed_4434 I see. You are welcome.

Comment: It's NOT entirely ok.  See my comment under the question. $\qquad$

Comment: @Ed_4434: I feel you. But for the record, it's okay here because $x^4 + 1$ is > 0 for all $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Start from
$$x^4-2x^2+1=(x^2-1)^2\ge0$$
which is true for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Then rearrange:
$$2x^2\le1+x^4$$
$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\le\frac12$$
where the last step is done because 2 and $1+x^4$ are always positive for $x\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks. As I said above, I tend to shy away from clearing denominators in case I drop solutions, which affects how I approach problems.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{x^{2} \over 1 + x^{4}} & =
{1 \over 1/x^{2} + x^{2}} =
{1 \over \pars{1/x - x}^{2} + 2} \color{#f00}{\leq \half}
\end{align}

> The equality is satisfied whenever $\ds{1/x - x = 0\quad\imp\quad x = \pm 1}$.